# Send weekly reminder to users that haven't completed a MS form

Tags: excel, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I have a question about PowerAutomate's capabilities. Let me describe what I'm trying to accomplish:
Each week, there are roughly 35 users (it's always the same users) that need to complete a MS Form. They have to complete this form by Wednesday. I'm wondering - is there a way that I can set up a recurring flow that runs on Thursday mornings that emails all the folks that haven't submitted a form response? Basically, I'm thinking the flow somehow needs to check to see if a response was submitted within the last 3 days, and if no, send an email the relevant user. How can I accomplish this? Do I need to use a combo of the recurring feature in PowerAutomate and the filter action? Any help is greatly appreciated!

For additional context - all form responses are automatically populated into an Excel and include the timestamp.

I've been getting a bit stumped on the set-up. I can see that it needs to be a recurring flow, but I'm unsure how to have it check against the list of 35 users each week.

Comment: Having no experience with Forms, I would put a formula in the Excel file to flag whether the most recent date for each user is in the current week, probably some combination of `WEEKNUM` and `MAXIF`. Then schedule a Flow to check the Excel file every Thursday morning and email whoever is flagged.